How do I resolve CORS Error that occurs when Redirecting to a URL?
I am attempting to implement a Google Authorization in my app. My frontend is React Native, and my backend is NodeJS(using Express).
I am successfully receiving my API call from my frontend(using Axios), but the problems occur on the last line of code in my backend function when I try to redirect. For testing purposes, I am currently just trying to redirect to Google. The error is the following:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/' (redirected from 'http://192.168.4.118:8000/getGoogleOAuthURL') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried many different configurations of CORS, but I don't seem to be having any luck. Can someone please advise how to successfully do a redirect without this CORS error? I have been stuck awhile :(.



StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/ChiomaGrace/MyKidsLeague

The authorization flow is initiated from the application installed on the user device by opening the browser and supplying a local redirect URI to handle responses.
See OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps  for details.

I am not too sure how that will help me. Can you explain further please?
I have manually created the uri that gets directed to Google authentication, and this works fine. The issue is the redirect doesn't occur because it says:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Social
So I am able to successfully call my google authentication function with CORS working and no issues, but then when this function tries to redirect, it says CORS is not there. Can you assist on how to fix this please?
